# Luxon does not return the right time with setLocale or with setZone even if if i check the timezone, it is correct

Tags: javascript, luxon

I have a string with this format, i am able to parse it and do operations with it, and it works perfectly on the frontend with the same functions.
The format is like so: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".
I use:

`DateTime.fromFormat(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").setLocale('fr').toFormat("HH:mm")`

When i check the locale it says (Europe/France) so i assume it is correctly setting the locale.
On the frontend it shows the right time, in the backend even if the locale is correct, it keeps displaying UTC time. Any ideas?